# vis.js with Google Fonts

Tags: javascript, vis.js

I am trying to use Open Sans with vis.js. While

```
  options: {
    nodes: {
      font: "22px arial #222222",
    },
```

works, I don't know how to get it to work with Google Fonts. Or rather with a font where the name isn't a single word.

This one doesn't work, but shows what I want to do:

```
  options: {
    nodes: {
      font: "22px OpenSans #222222",
    },
```

Edit: the problem is **not** the Google Font import, since this one works:

```
  options: {
    nodes: {
      font: "22px Nunito #222222",
    },
```

Comment: Shot in the dark but can you wrap the font name in single quotes?

Comment: thanks, should've mentioned I tried it already, but it doesn't work either

Answer (score 0):

According to vis.js docs, the font option can be either a string or an object. Try configuring it as an object with this form:

```
    font: {
        size: 22,
        face: 'OpenSans',
        color: '#222222'
    }
```

Note that the size should be an integer if you choose this option.
Make sure that the font name you pass to the face property is the same as your font family name provided by Google Fonts if you added the font via font  (eg. 'Open Sans')

https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/docs/network/nodes.html